# How to weight the quotient of sums as a dependent variable for a regression in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Edit - Rewrote question since the original did not makes sense:

In R - how would I go about getting a lm fit model that is a quotient of sums for two variables grouped by a third factor variable, but that weights some entries more than others? Data looks like:

```
Browser       Visits    Clicks
Chrome         100       25
Chrome         89        40
Chrome         10        0
Safari         40        10
Safari         30        2
```

From the comments this is the command for the WLS regression weighted by visits, but I don't think I'm using the weight function right since I don't know how the errors are correlated with visits, just that they are.

```
fit <- lm(Clicks/Visits ~ Browser, weights=(visits/sum(visits)))
```

Comment: your regression does not make any sense since if you aggregate, there would only be one observation per browser. i think what you are looking for is a regression of the form `lm(Clicks/Visits ~ Browser)`

Comment: yes - looking now I simplified it too much and should have included the other variables I had in the regression to prevent it from collapsing to a single observation. The problem with clicks/visits ~ Browser is that it weights every observation the same when some (like those with more visits) should probably get more weight. Any suggestion on showing those weights in the regression?

Comment: `lm` has a `weights` argument, as it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for a rate model, i.e. events per number at risk. This is usually implemented by modeling the process as a Poisson distributed set of events:

```
    dat <- read.table(textConnection("Browser       Visits    Clicks
 Chrome         100       25
 Chrome         89        40
 Chrome         10        0
 Safari         40        10
 Safari         30        2"), header=TRUE)

 dat$CperV <- with(dat, Clicks/Visits)
    dat


 glm(CperV ~ Browser, data=dat, family = "poisson")

Call:  glm(formula = CperV ~ Browser, family = "poisson", data = dat)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)  BrowserSafari  
       -1.456         -0.387  

Degrees of Freedom: 4 Total (i.e. Null);  3 Residual
Null Deviance:      0.772 
Residual Deviance: 0.7379   AIC: Inf 
    Residual Deviance: 0.1182   AIC: 1.467 

> exp(-1.456  ) # estimated rate for nonSafari Visits
[1] 0.2331671
> exp(-1.456-0.387 ) # estimated rate for Safari Visits
[1] 0.1583417
> mean(dat[dat$Browser=="Safari",  "CperV"])  # actual means
[1] 0.1583333
> mean(dat[dat$Browser!="Safari",  "CperV"])  # actual means
[1] 0.2331461
```